# Voltage divider with ac source

Tags: voltage-divider

[image]

Left side of the voltage divider is a bit confusing. How would AC react with DC voltage?
Considering a high frequency ac source, capacitor would act as a wire. So what will be the output voltage?
Logical answer instead of a mathematical one would be more appreciable.

Comment: You can treat AC and DC separately. What is the DC voltage at Vout? Now suppose Vin is a 1 Volt AC signal with a frequency so high that the capacitor can be considered a short (for the AC, not the DC!). So what will be the AC signal at Vout? What was the DC at Vout? Now combine the two (just add them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vout would be 1 volt DC superimposed with the AC signal applied at the input. However, if the input frequency is quite low, the output AC content will be small. The cut-off point of this high-pass circuit is 14.468 kHz and this is the 3 dB point. Frequencies significantly above this would not suffer attenuation and frequencies significantly below this would suffer higher attenuation.